# Google tutorial: Number of samples / number of words per sample ratio

Tags: classification, natural-language

I am working through a Google tutorial on text classification which you find here: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-2-5
A decisive measure to figure out which model to use is here the "number of samples/number of words per sample ratio".
How is this ratio to be understood? Given the examples used, the samples seem to be the single texts of a corpus (lines), while the columns contain the features (n-grams); but what is the number of words per sample? Should you take the average number of words per sample?
Or is this ratio simply the number of lines (samples) divided by the number of columns (features)?
Thanks!
Requin

Comment: Somebody have an idea?

Comment: Just go to step 2.There you will find an explanation of those metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means the ratio of (Number of samples)/(Number of words per sample). In the case in Step 2, this ratio should be (25000)/(174) = 143